# working with lot of checkboxes controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a lot of checkboxes present in the webpage. So, basically structure is like this::

Checkbox Yes   CheckboxNo
Textbox

So , I have about hundredes of the above sets whcih contains two checkboxes showing yes or no with a textbox for it's explanation.My query is that when a user clicks yes, the textbox will be enable and otherwise it will be disable.That's good I can do that and did in some of my pages like this::
IsProcess is a class given to each set of checkboxes so that I can work over it.
CheckboxYes is Id of checkbox that is representing the "yes"
TextboxId is the id of textbox which is defaulted to disable.

view page

```
<div style="width: 100%; float: left; padding-bottom: 10px;"> 
    <span style="width: 100%; float: left; line-height: 20px;">Do you currently have thoughts of wishing you were dead?</span>
    <div style="width: 10%; float: left;">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.WishingDeadNo, new { @class = "Wishing", @onclick = "Checkme(this.className);" }) No</div>
    <div style="width: 30%; float: left;">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.WishingDeadYes, new { @class = "Wishing", @onclick = "Checkme(this.className);" }) Yes ,explain</div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 60%;">@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.WishingDeadExplanation, new { @readonly = "readonly" })</div>
</div>
```

Script::

```
$('.Wishing').click(function () {
        if ($("#WishingDeadYes").is(':checked')) {
            $("#WishingDeadExplanation").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else {
            $("#WishingDeadExplanation").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#WishingDeadExplanation").val('');
        }
    });
```

So I am okay with this but problem arrives when you have hundreds of above sets.
I have to write thousands of above lines.Please help.

Comment: How about posting the actual HTML instead

Comment: I do'nt know about it.

Comment: If you don't know what the HTML looks like, how do you intend to target the right elements ?

Comment: I know how Html looks like but I do'nt know how to post HTMl

Comment: Same way you posted the javascript

Comment: Okay , you are asking to post the html in the question. I thought you are asking to post HTMl to server. just a minute I am updating it.

Comment: Yes, just post an example of the HTML in the question so we know how the elements are related to each other

Comment: I have updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: Yeah, that's the serverside code, I don't really read ASP, but maybe someone else does ?

Comment: no Problem. Thank you for giving your precious time.

Comment: Looking at the code and what your are saying, seems you want to bind a model which is actually a Collection of items. This way the names that would be rendered for each `Checkbox` Yes or No in format like `[0].CheckBoxYes` and `[0].CheckBoxNo` and `[0].YourTextbox`. This way you can find out the textbox you are dealing with (with the name or ID attr) for a particular set of checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can have different classes for both checkboxes like.

```
<div style="width: 100%; float: left; padding-bottom: 10px;"> 
    <span style="width: 100%; float: left; line-height: 20px;">Do you currently have thoughts of wishing you were dead?</span>
    <div style="width: 10%; float: left;">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.WishingDeadNo, new { @class = "WishingNo", @onclick = "Checkme(this.className);" }) No</div>
    <div style="width: 30%; float: left;">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.WishingDeadYes, new { @class = "WishingYes", @onclick = "Checkme(this.className);" }) Yes ,explain</div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 60%;">@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.WishingDeadExplanation, new { @readonly = "readonly" })</div>
</div>
```

then bind event to only WishingYes checkbox. and event if you are going to have thousand sets same as above you need not write different code.

**Note** that I have written code supposing that you are going to have same design as above for every set of checkbox and textarea

```
 $('.WishingYes').click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().next('div').find("textarea").removeAttr("disabled");

        }
        else {
        $(this).parent().next('div').find("textarea").prop("disabled", "disabled");
        $(this).parent().next('div').find("textarea").val('');
        }
    });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Sr434/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="abc" value="yes">

<Script type="text/javascript">
    $(.abc).is(':checked'))
    {
    //set your value here
    }
    </Script>
```